MS Word IF Reference not working when selecting from Form Drop Down
I'm trying to link address lines (IF References) to a location dropdown list but it doesn't seem to work.
Please see snippet of code below, what is wrong with the code cause when I select a location nothing happens, even after pressing TAB on keyboard. (PS. Calculate on exist is enabled)
Code Snippet
Thanks in advance

Please try to convert the field code into text rather than image format. Many people here will ignore your question because of that, and also possibly because many don't think of Word Field Code issues as "programming" issues,

Suggestion one is that you haven't checked "Calculate on Exit" in the DROPDOWN  options (in the dialog box).

Suggestion two is that it's possible (thought not very common I suspect) for the bookmark, in this case Himoinsabranch, to be moved so that it doesn't "cover" the DROPDOWN result - then, you are unlikely to get a match! FOr example, if for reason you put a { SET HimoinsaBranch "something" } field somewhere in the form and executed it, that would happen. If you actually have a SET or ASK field that uses that bookmark name, delete them. Then, in all cases, recreating the dropdown is probably the easiest way to get the bookmark back in the correct place.
